# tostring("000.0") generating wrong value

Tags: c#, string, tostring

In my c# console application, I want to convert double variable to string type.  but resultant string variable should have at least 3 digit to left of decimal point and one digit to right of it.
example: 3.4569 should converted to "003.4"

It works for above example, but throws wrong result for following conversion.

```
 double Num = Math.Pow((3 + Math.Sqrt(5)), N); //6578336356630531.0 for N=22
 string StringNum = Num .ToString("000.0");
```

It results..

```
 StringNum ="6578336356630530.0";
```

but it would be..

```
 StringNum ="6578336356630531.0";
```

How do i get exact string value for these type of numbers??

```
 //decimal Num=Convert.ToDecimal (Math.Pow((3 + Math.Sqrt(5)), N));
 //this conversion also looses original value
```

Thanx..

Comment: It seems you are on the edge of precision. Try `if (6578336356630531.0 == 6578336356630530.0) Console.WriteLine("Precision problem");`

Comment: I am getting N=22 as input 
and then i used N as following, 
Num=Math.Pow((3 + Math.Sqrt(5)), N); //6578336356630531.0
so for Math functions i used double variable..

Comment: @durgesh.patle kay bhau, tya yed*** ghabarun tumhi post delete kelit? aaho marathi aahat tumhi marathi...

Comment: @durgesh.patle hi aapali hakkachi chat room aahe http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26688/maharashtrian-code-worriars ithe pahije teva yet ja...bola maharashtra navanirman senechaaaa

Comment: @Freelancer: ...vijay aso, ghabarun post delete nahi keli bhau, -ve points mule post delete keli., chat room chya mahitisathi dhanyawad..

Comment: ok..ok...lakshat theva stackoverflow aapalya hakkach...nahi konachya bapach..he bh**ve kon tharavanare marathi manasani konachya bhashet aani kuthe bolayach..jai maharashtra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is the value you're storing *is* exactly `6578336356630531`. There is no `double` value closer to 6578336356630530. So the output is correct for the data present at execution time.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx):

> All floating-point numbers also have a limited number of significant digits, which also determines how accurately a floating-point value approximates a real number. A Double value has up to 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

You're quibbling about the 16th digit.

I have a [handy class](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which lets you see the *exact* value of any `double`.

If you need more precision than that, use `decimal` instead of `double`. Note that `decimal` has a smaller *range* but higher precision.

Comment: Thanx sir, but    
I am getting N=22 as input and used as following,   Num=Math.Pow((3 + Math.Sqrt(5)), N); //6578336356630531.0 so for Math functions i used double variable, I can not use pow or sqrt with decimal

Comment: @durgesh.patle: Well you just need to understand that if you're using `double`, you should ignore anything beyond the 15th significant digit. The number you're trying to get to is fundamentally unrepresentable as a `double.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a decimal?

```
decimal Num = 6578336356630531.0M;
string StringNum = Num .ToString("000.0");
```

`double` is a float which approximates precision. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Article excerpt:

> Floating-Point Values and Loss of Precision
>
> Remember that a
> floating-point number can only approximate a decimal number, and that
> the precision of a floating-point number determines how accurately
> that number approximates a decimal number. By default, a Double value
> contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17
> digits is maintained internally. The precision of a floating-point
> number has several consequences: Two floating-point numbers that
> appear equal for a particular precision might not compare equal
> because their least significant digits are different. A mathematical
> or comparison operation that uses a floating-point number might not
> yield the same result if a decimal number is used because the
> floating-point number might not exactly approximate the decimal
> number. A value might not roundtrip if a floating-point number is
> involved. A value is said to roundtrip if an operation converts an
> original floating-point number to another form, an inverse operation
> transforms the converted form back to a floating-point number, and the
> final floating-point number is equal to the original floating-point
> number. The roundtrip might fail because one or more least significant
> digits are lost or changed in a conversion.

Comment: I am taking N as input 
and then i used N as following, 
Num=Math.Pow((3 + Math.Sqrt(5)), N); //6578336356630531.0 for N=22
so for Math functions i used double variable..

Answer (score 0):

Use `decimal` instead of `double` and everything will be OK:

```
decimal Num = 6578336356630531.0m;
string StringNum = Num.ToString("000.0");
```

The problem is connected with double values representation and precision.

Answer (score 0):

`double` cannot store that amount of precision. Use a `decimal` if that's the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you have found a number that cannot be represented by a floating-point numkber correctly.

try using a decimal instead:

```
decimal Num = 6578336356630531.0m;
string StringNum = Num.ToString("###.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximal whole number without rounding in double precision is 2^53 - 1, which is approx 9e15, but you have 6e15, which may possibly be represented preciously, but not necessarily. You had a bad luck (quite often type of bad luck; deal with it). If you want to live without these surprises, you have to use decimal type in c#.

Comment: mistake: the max precision for no rounding is 2^52 - 1, this makes your number exceed the limit and it is no luck, its certainity that it be rounded.